# Writing to a global variable with different processes in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a global variable to which I want to write in with different processes (code below).
I use a reentrant lock to avoid race conditions (writing to the same place with many threads).
Interestingly it seems that the global variable doesn't get modified at all, but using only the main thread modifies it successfully (bar function).
How can I write to a global variable with different processes?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Pool
from threading import RLock

lock = RLock()
global_counter = 0
def foo(num):
    global global_counter
    print(num) # prints 3,4,5
    with lock:
        global_counter = global_counter + 1

def bar():
    global global_counter
    with lock:
        global_counter = global_counter + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    list(p.map(foo, [3,4,5]))
    print(global_counter) # prints 0
    bar()
    print(global_counter) # prints 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processes behave differently from threads, and specifically, they don’t share memory. Global variables are copied into the respective process which means their value in the main process doesn’t change - which is what caused the confusion in the question.

However, as stated in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes there are ways to share memory between processes if that is necessary.

In this case, we can simply use a shared memory map using a "Value" object

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Pool, Value
from threading import RLock

lock = RLock()
global_counter = 0
def foo(num):
    global global_counter
    print(num) # prints 3,4,5
    with lock:
        global_counter.value = global_counter.value + 1

def bar():
    global global_counter
    with lock:
        global_counter.value = global_counter.value + 1


def global_test():
    global global_counter
    global_counter = Value('d', 0)
    p = Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    list(p.map(foo, [3,4,5]))
    print(global_counter) # prints 3
    bar()
    print(global_counter) # prints 4
```